# How do I pass the values from my form into an email body using MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok so, I have a contact form on my website. I have the ability to send the email with the labels, but I can't seem to get the values to send. So, essentially my Email will look like

First Name:

Last Name:

Company:

Comments:

I just want to know what I am doing wrong.

**Controller**

> ```
>     [HttpGet]
>     public IActionResult Contact()
>     {
>         ViewData["Message"] = "Contact Us TODAY!";            
>         return View();
>     }
>
>
>     [HttpPost]
>     public IActionResult SendEmail()
>     {
>
>         var NewContact = new Forms();
>         string body = "First Name: " + NewContact.FirstName + "\n"
>                             + "Last Name:" + NewContact.LastName + "\n"
>                             + "Company:" + NewContact.Company + "\n\n"
>                             + "Comments:" + NewContact.Comments;
>         MailMessage mailBody = new MailMessage("Something@example.com", "Somethingelse@example.com");
>         mailBody.Subject = "Contact Form";
>         mailBody.Body = body;
>
>         SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.aol.com", 587);
>         smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
>         {
>             UserName = UserNameHidden,
>             Password = PasswordHidden
>         };
>
>         smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
>         smtpClient.Send(mailBody);
>
>         return Redirect("Contact");
>     }
> ```

**View Page**

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SendEmail" name="ContactUs" method="post" class="bs-example-form">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="FirstName" placeholder="First Name*" type="text" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="LastName" placeholder="Last Name*" type="text" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="PhoneNumber">Phone:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="PhoneNumber" type="tel" asp-format="000-000-0000" onloosefocus="format"  placeholder="Phone Number*" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Email">Email:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email*" title="example@meems.org" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="formspacer"></span><hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Company">Company:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Company" placeholder="Company*" title="If you do not represent a company, please type 'NONE'." required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Company" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="StreetAddress">Street Address:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="StreetAddress" placeholder="Street Address*" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="StreetAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="City">City:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="City" placeholder="City*" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="State">State:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="State" placeholder="State*" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ZipCode">Zip:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="ZipCode" placeholder="Zip Code*" required />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 bg-grey">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Comments">Comments:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" asp-for="Comments" placeholder="Comments" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="buttonWrapper text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" role="button">Reset</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" role="button" title="Coming Soon Please Just Email Us With This Information">Send</button>
```

**Model**

```
public class Forms
    {
        //Company Contact Information Customer
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }

        //Company Address Customer
        [Required]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendEmail()
{
    var NewContact = new Forms();
   // Existing code
}
```

You are creating a totally new object of `Forms` class. This new object properties will have the default values, not the values you have in the form you posted.

What you can do is, Add a parameter to the `SendEmail` action method of type `Forms`. When the form is submitted, the DefaultModelBinder will map the form fields to the parameter as the property names matches with the form field names.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendEmail(Forms NewContact)
{       
   // Existing code which reads from NewContact object property values
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been driving me crazy and I never even thought about that.

Comment: Quick question: why a return type of IActionResult instead of ActionResult?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new Forms object rather than passing it in a parameter in you post method. So the fields are all initialized to default values.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, you need to pass a model as an argument to your controller method.

You also need to check model's validation state before using its values, and (typically) return the same view if model is invalid, so validation errors are shown to user.

So your method might be something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendEmail(Forms NewContact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // model is valid, you can send email now

        string body = "First Name: " + NewContact.FirstName + "\n"
                            + "Last Name:" + NewContact.LastName + "\n"
                            + "Company:" + NewContact.Company + "\n\n"
                            + "Comments:" + NewContact.Comments;
        MailMessage mailBody = new MailMessage("Something@example.com", "Somethingelse@example.com");
        mailBody.Subject = "Contact Form";
        mailBody.Body = body;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.aol.com", 587);
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
        {
            UserName = UserNameHidden,
            Password = PasswordHidden
        };

        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(mailBody);

        return Redirect("Contact");
    }
    else
    {
        // model contains validation errors
        // return the same view so form is populated with existing values, 
        // and validation errors are shown
        //
        // You are responsible for populating model values in view page
        // it will be done automatically if you're using tag helpers like @Html.EditorFor()

        return View("Contact", model);
    }
}
```

Also sending mail might take some time, so you'd better make your controller method asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am using client side validation for this form. So, the submit button will not submit the form unless validated.

Comment: That can easily fail to work if there's JS load issue, or the attacker fakes a request by submitting manually-constructed form. So you should always check model state on server side too (also it costs nothing, because the model is validated nevertheless, you just check the result).

Comment: Also not all validation types can be made on client side. For example, you might want to return error if the specified email already exists in subscription database. It is reasonable to perform such validation on server side only, while the simple ones are performed on client side first.

Comment: I understand that, and I would be worried if I were submitting to a database. This is for a simple SMTP to send me an email.

Comment: I believe it is better to always use a solid validation pattern, regardless of the code doing something harmful or not. So if you (or someone who will maintain your code) add writing to database in the future, you won't forget to validate it.